# sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This Pipeline instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator

Tags: python, graphviz

I want to draw a decisiontree. But my data is text data. So I used Pipeline. However, the same error as the title appears. Please tell me how I can plot a tree with my data using graphviz or plot tree

```
data_files = 'dataset2-Komoran.xlsx'

data = pd.read_excel(data_files)
train_data = data[['title','category','processed_title']]
categories=train_data['category']
labels=list(set(categories))
n_classes=len(labels)
print('possible categories',labels)
for l in labels:
    print('number of ', l, len(train_data.loc[train_data['category']==l]))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data['processed_title'],train_data['category'],test_size=0.2,random_state=57)
model = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                     ('clf', DecisionTreeClassifier()),
                     ])


model.fit(X_train, y_train)

export_graphviz(model,
                out_file='tree.dot'
               )
```